# Namespace ('ns') Issue with Shiny Modules: CheckboxInput Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: r, shiny, module, namespaces

In my provided example outside a module, everything works smoothly. However, when I try to add a namespace (ns) to the checkbox inside a module, it seems to cause issues. I need to create a module within my app, and I'm concerned that not having its own namespace might lead to problems within a more complex app.

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Checkbox and Conditional Panel Example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("addArguments", "Arguments"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.addArguments",
        textInput("customArguments", "Add custom arguments:")
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Content:"),
      verbatimTextOutput("contentOutput")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contentOutput <- renderText({
    if (input$addArguments) {
      paste("Checkbox 'Arguments' is selected. Custom Arguments:", input$customArguments)
    } else {
      "Checkbox 'Arguments' is not selected."
    }
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

second example not working as expected

```
library(shiny)


checkboxConditionalUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    checkboxInput(("addArguments"), "Arguments"),
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.addArguments",
        textInput(inputId = ns("customArguments"),label = "Add custom arguments"
        )

    )
  )
}


checkboxConditional <- function(input, output, session) {
 
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Checkbox and Conditional Panel Module Example"),
  checkboxConditionalUI("myModule1"),
)

checkboxConditional <- function(input, output, session) {
 
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The `condition` in `conditionalPanel` is a JavaScript expression. It doesn’t  know about Shiny namespaces, so you need to add them manually. Personally, I’d use `uiOutput` instead.  `checkboxInput(("addArguments"), "Arguments")` looks odd. Did you mean `checkboxInput(ns("addArguments"), "Arguments")` instead?

Comment: this is exactly what I find strange. If ytou use ns in addArgumets it doesn't work anything anymore. Have you got any link or suggestions about the uiOutput?

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.  You don't reference the module server in the main server function (so Shiny "optimises" it out); you define `checkboxConditional` twice, and don't pass it the module id.  But the fundamental issue is that you don't use the `ns` argument of `conditionalPanel` to help JavaScript sort out the namespace issue.

This appears to give you what you want, though it is different from your non-module UI:

```
ibrary(shiny)

checkboxConditionalUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    checkboxInput(ns("addArguments"), "Arguments"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.addArguments",
      ns = ns,
      textInput(inputId = ns("customArguments"), label = "Add custom arguments")
    )
  )
}

checkBoxConditional <- function(id) {}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Checkbox and Conditional Panel Module Example"),
  checkboxConditionalUI("myModule1"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  checkBoxConditional("myModule1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[Current best ptactice](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/) suggests that you should define your module server like this:

```
checkBoxConditional <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {}
  )
}
```

[And, personally, I'd rename `checkboxConditional` to `checkboxConditionalServer`.]

A solution based on `outputUI` might look something like this:

```
library(shiny)

checkboxConditionalUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    checkboxInput(ns("addArguments"), "Arguments"),
    uiOutput(ns("customArgumentsUI"))
  )
}

checkBoxConditional <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      output$customArgumentsUI <- renderUI({
        if (input$addArguments) {
          textInput(inputId = ns("customArguments"), label = "Add custom arguments")
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Checkbox and Conditional Panel Module Example"),
  checkboxConditionalUI("myModule1"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  checkBoxConditional("myModule1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly the second one is the one I was searching for!